# React Navigation navigation.replace() Crashes app inside useEffect

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

I have a screen where I check if this is the first time a user launches the app and then navigate to the appropriate screen. Anytime the `navigation.replace()` function gets triggered, the app crashes. Below is the code. what am I doing wrong?

````
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native-paper'

export default function RedirectScreen({ navigation }) {
  function navigateAway(routeName) {
    navigation.replace(routeName)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      SecureStore.getItemAsync('initialLaunch').then((val) => {
        if (val) {
          navigateAway('AuthScreen')
        } else {
          SecureStore.setItemAsync('initialLaunch', 'yes').catch((err) =>
            console.log(err),
          )

          navigateAway('Onboarding')
        }
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider
      style={{
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <ActivityIndicator />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  )
}```
````

Comment: Share your error message as well

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it's stated that navigation.replace only works **if the navigator is a stack navigator**.

Now I can't really tell if this is your issue cause you didn't share the exact error you get when the app crashes, but it seems to me you can handle the case you describe a bit differently.

I suggest you follow the documentation example for authentication flows here

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

Basically you can set a state variable like isFirstLoad and then inside your Navigator do something like:

```
<Navigator>
    {isFirstLoad ? (
      <Navigator.Screen
        name="Onboarding"
        component={Onboarding}
      />
    ) : (
      <Navigator.Screen
        name="AuthScreen"
        component={AuthScreen}
      />
    )}
</Navigator>
```

Comment: Well, I'm using stack navigation, and have tried the auth flow method also but the crash happened anyways. The app crashes, I mean closes without any errors.  It closes abruptly without any errors at all.

Comment: Hm this is strange, maybe you should check the terminal that opens when the project runs and check for any errors there. There must be something logged somewhere :)

Comment: Ok.  But it seems to work fine when I build an APK but doesn't when running in Expo go.

Answer (score 0):

`navigation.replace()` gets app crash in both android and ios but `navigation.navigate()` works fine in my case.